# JavaScript - Trying to return null when phone number string equals nine characters

Tags: javascript, string, function, jasmine, this

I'm having trouble with a code test for a job I'm applying for. The test is using Jasmine for testing, and I'm having difficulty getting test 9 to pass. I've already passed the first 3 tests using the .replace to remove all punctuation and spaces, but now I'm stuck. I'm pretty green when it comes to JavaScript.

The test wants me to return null when a string of numbers only contains 9 numbers.

Here's my code. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var PhoneNumber = function (string) {
  this.phone = string;
};

PhoneNumber.prototype.number = function () {
  return this.phone.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
  if (this.phone.length === 9) {
    return null;
  };
};



module.exports = PhoneNumber;
```

Comment: The function exits at first `return`. Moreover, `.replace()` is not mutative, hence you should write `s = this.phone.replace(...)`.

Comment: Move the first return to the bottom?

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to return null when it's *not* 9 numbers? Seems backward to return null in one specific length case for a phone number.

Comment: @Mark_M Considering the job of this function, its name itself seems *awkward* :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

The problem is that when you use the return keyword the function in layman's terms 'ends'. So when you execute the line

```
return this.phone.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
```

It will terminate the function and therefore not let you return null. The simplest solution to the problem is as follows:

```
PhoneNumber.prototype.number = function () {
   if (this.phone.length === 9) {
      return null;
   }
   return this.phone.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
};
```

That way you will return null if you need to and if not you can process the string. By the way, you don't need the semicolon at the end of the if statement bracket.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the places of the `if` statement.

```
var PhoneNumber = function (string) {
    this.phone = string;
};

PhoneNumber.prototype.number = function () {
    if (this.phone.length === 9) {               // <----- Here
        return null;
    };
    return this.phone.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
};

module.exports = PhoneNumber;
```

Comment: By the gods! Also, D'Oh! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @JacobSchaefer Please accept this answer to close the question.